How can I enable CUDA in PyTorch for Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 Ti?
I want to run the PyTorch library, which I am running in a virtual environment in PyCharm, on my graphics card, which is an Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 Ti. However, it's running on the CPU, and whenever I use the command import torch and print("cuda is available:", torch.cuda.is_available()), it always returns False.
I have CUDA version 12.6 installed. I also installed PyTorch for CUDA version 12.4 because it was the latest version available on the PyTorch website. What should I install considering my graphics card type?

hmm.. what message shows when you type nvcc -V in your command prompt?

It shows 12.6 version

You need to download the version of Pytorch that is compatible with CUDA for that, head over to the website: https://pytorch.org/

Download the latest one (12.4) and Run the command that is shown in the image on your Command Terminal.
Then Install Cuda same version (12.4) URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-12-4-0-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exe_local

Then check the commands,
Nvidia-smi
nvcc --version 

Ensure the versions for Pytorch & CUDA are same, Hope this helps!

This is wrong in several ways. Modern PyTorch distributions from the official build source ship with all the required CUDA runtime libraries. It is not required to install a CUDA toolkit to run PyTorch. All that is required is an NVIDIA driver which has a minimum supported  CUDA runtime version greater than or equal to the CUDA runtime version that the installed PyTorch version was built against. There is no requirement that the CUDA version shown by nvidia-smi matches

There are 2 versions of CUDA installed on your computer:

the driver version, (shown by nvidia-smi, also called CUDA-toolkit) is the version that is installed when you update your driver, this is the cuda used any time some process want execute something in GPU. This should be the most recent one (or so) in any cases
the runtime version, it's the cuda used specifically by Pytorch to make parallelized computations via its routines. The version of pytorch and the runtime version should match. The driver-CUDA is called after the runtime routines, the calling scheme is:

Pytorch Python API -> Pytorch C++ API -> runtime CUDA routines -> local driver CUDA -> GPU
Since Pytorch 2.0 the runtime cuda libraries are automatically installed in your environment so you only need to update your nvidia drivers (and upgrade pip) before calling pip install torch
Make sure your python version is 3.9+ (using a virtual environment is highly recommended). Your graphic card is quite recent so there is no problem regarding it (some old graphic card could have cuda compatibility issues)
pip install torch should install torch==2.5.1 with runtime cuda 12.4 if everything is good (most recent version when I'm writing this)

I've just encountered same problem, same CUDA 12.6 as your etc., and as advised by Grok, I used (on Windows 11 machine):
PS C:\Users\nenad> pip install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu126
Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu126

and it worked! Of course it is "night" build, but I don't want to wait for stable release.

I am assuming you are talking about CUDA version 12.6 that is mentioned when you run the nvidia-smi command in terminal.
This shows the version of CUDA that is supported by your GPU and does not mean that CUDA 12.6 is installed on your system.
You need to run the following commands based on OS:
On Windows System:
pip3 install torch --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124

On Linux System:
pip3 install torch

Note: Also make sure your virtual environment is active in pycharm terminal before running the above pip commands.
